# Can you activate a button in a hover popup using the keyboard in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can display a hover popup with ⌘K ⌘I (on Mac). Is there a way to trigger a button on the popup (such as *Quick Fix...* in the image below) without using the mouse?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other actions, but specifically for `Quick Fix...` there is a keyboard shortchut.

On a Mac it is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: Thankyou. I appreciate that answer -- I didn't know that, and that's all I really want to do in this case.